# Divisors of zero in $ \mathbb Z_{p^k}$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $p$ be a prime numer and let $k$ be a natural numer such that $k\geq 2$. I wish to descripe all zero's divisors in $\mathbb Z_{p^k}$. Obviously elements of the form
$np$, where $n=0,...,p^{k-1}-1$, are zero divisors, because $p^k|np^k$.
Are there  others?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $ab=0$, and $p\nmid a$.  Well $p^k|ab$, so $p^k|b$, so $b=0$.  Hence you found them all.

Comment: Thanks.  Maybe still one trivial question to the answer: why if $p\nmid a$ and $p^k|ab$ then $p^k|b$ (I know than then $p|b$ but why $p^k|b$?

Comment: @Alex I is true from basic theorems on prime factorisation. But you  can also see it like this. Suppose $k\gt 1$, then $b=pc$ and $p^{k-1}|ac$, whence $p|c$ - and following this through all the factors of $p$ must be contained in $b$.